# link a latex file to another latex file

Tags: hyperref, links

I am writing a long technical report and instead of linking "names" to a specific "url or webpage" I want to link it to another tex file on which I have total control of the content.

I tried to use:
`\href{run:/path/to/my/file.ext}{text displayed}`
... but not working.

For instance,
Let say I have the text " Mr. X is the main scientist", I want to be able to link "Mr. X" to another *.tex file

code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document}
 \href{run:/test.pdf}{This is my link} or
\href{file:/test.pdf}{This is my link} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should that be `file://path/to/my/file.pdf`? I assume you want to open another pdf file? Or are you trying to replace that text with what's in the file.tex? Or are you really looking for a tool-tip so that when you hover over the data some information appears?

Comment: if you are reading that text in a pdf reader what do you want to happen when you click on the link?

Comment: Herb and David: When you clink on the link in the pdf main document "Mr X", I want it to open another pdf file.                       I tried \href{} with either run or file and it does create the link in a green box but when I click on it nothing happens.  thank you for your time and considerations

Comment: @jean: Comments are not meant for code sections really. Please add it to your post above